# Custom View Controller Transitions From UICollection View

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, uiviewanimation, uiviewanimationtransition

I have 3 view controllers, all having a collection view in them with different layouts, everything works well and the only thing my question focuses on is the custom transition between view controllers introduced in iOS7 with the UIView animation block.

View Controllers

VC1: All Presentations view controller where there are thumbnails of all the presentations a user has. It's a 3xn collection view of thumbnail images scrolling vertically. At a time a max of 9 cells can be seen on the screen in VC1.

VC2: After selecting a specific presentation in VC1, we come to the next view controller which shows all the slides in that presentation. At a time 30 cells at max can be seen on the screen in VC2.

VC3: On tapping any slide from VC2, we come to VC3 where the same image is displayed on the whole screen. At max 2 slides can be seen on the screen at the same time (when user is scrolling to the next slide) in VC3.

Now here is the problem:

There are two options for the user,

option1: the user goes from vc1 -> vc2 -> vc3
option2: there is an illusion that the user goes from vc1 to vc3 directly, but because when popping vc3, I need to come to vc 2 and not vc1, so on view will appear of vc2, I push vc3.

Between vc2 and vc3 there is a custom transition that happens, which is a zooming effect where it seems like a cell from vc2 zooms in.

When the user does option1, the transition is a bit laggy, when user chooses option 2, it works perfectly fine. I do not really get the reason why.

- I use small sized images for when displaying the cells in vc2
- I am loading images in an async manner as well
- I saw in some other places to make sure the background is white and not clear color, done that
- There is no real difference that is happening between option 1 and 2, only as I explained.

Why would one have a lag in transition and the other be smooth ? I am not sure which code would you like to see so if you comment what you would like to see, I can paste something.

Thank You for your time.

Comment: You don't need to go to vc2 when going to vc1 from vc3. I'll show you what I mean more in answer. Just use `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];` in vc3

Answer (score 0):

For option one, create a segue in the storyboard from vc1 to vc3. and use it like this:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"1to3"
                          sender:self];
```

Also, add this to VC3 when you want to go back to VC1

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Here's an example project cuz I was bored:

https://github.com/MichaelSnowden/StackOverflow

**EDIT:**

In case you just want to go from vc3 to vc2, just use this from within vc3:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for your time @doctordoder, I get what you are saying and this was how it was initially set up. Consider vc3 to be the slide show view and vc2 to be the view where you can see all slides. So in the slideshow view, you see a slide in full screen. So in the option the user has is to directly start in slideshow view (vc3) or see all the slides in the presentation as thumbs (vc2). Regardless of which case is chosen, when popping from vc3, I need to come to vc2, not vc1 and hence need vc2 to be part of the navigation controller stack. I hope my explanation was clear.

Comment: I checked out the project. Thanks for your time. The thing maybe I did not explain well enough. From vc3, going to vc1 should not be possible without going to vc2 first. vc1 can go to vc2 or vc3, vc2 can go back to vc 1 or push to vc3. vc3 can only come back to vc1, should not be allowed to go to vc1. Do the lag is cause by having too many vc's in the navigation controller stack ?